# Openshift + Tomcat9 + JSF -> jsf.application.resource.unable_to_create_compression_directory

Tags: containers, openshift, tomcat9, jsf-2.3

I'm getting this error when deploying a JSF Mojarra 2.3 application in Tomcat 9.0.26 in Red Hat OpenShift:

```
WARN   [https-jsse-nio2-8443-exec-4] j.e.r.w.j.resource - jsf.application.resource.unable_to_create_compression_directory
```

I think another problem is that the message key is not resolved to:

```
JSF1065: Unable to create directory {0} to store compressed resource.
```

But that aside, in openshift I don't have any write permission. How can I fix this issue? I hadn't it with Tomcat 8.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I simply created an `emptyDir` volume + mount, see https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/dev_guide/volumes.html:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      volumes:
        # Catalina scratch dir
        - name: catalina-work
          emptyDir: {}
      containers:
        volumeMounts:
          - name: catalina-work
            mountPath: /tomcat/work
```